# UITableViewCell subview animation timing weirdness

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to start an animation inside of a UITableViewCell, but it won't start unless I do something silly.  The code is getting called, but the animation just does nothing as is.  If I delay it by putting it inside a `dispatch_async` then it will work.  Why does this happen?  What do I need to wait for in order for the animation to start?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(mNeedsAnimation)
    {
    //this will delay it a bit and make it work, but why?
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ (
        mViewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
        mViewToAnimate.hidden = NO;
        mViewToAnimate.alpha = 1.f;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
            mViewToAnimate.alpha = 0.0;
            mViewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.f, 1.f);
        }completion:nil];
    //});
        mNeedsAnimation = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because when willDisplayCell gets called the cell is still offscreen and can not have an animation.

Comment: I thought something like that...but if that is the case, then this code is so fragile.  Do you know of anything that will alert me to the fact that this cell is on screen and ready to receive animations?

Comment: maybe mViewToAnimate.superview

Comment: Interesting theory, I will test it out when I get a moment.  +1 for now though.

Comment: The client's request changed completely so I no longer need to do things this way, but from some limited testing, it appears that it is OK to start an animation in `didMoveToSuperview` so I think this answer is correct.